# Store and retrieve integer value in Flutter using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I want to add a high score feature to a quiz app and retain the value using shared preferences. I would then like to display this back to the user if they click an icon on the landing page. I have seen a similar question asked and the code example for shared preferences they gave looked like this:

Get:

```
  Future<void> getHighScore() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _highscore = prefs.getInt('highScore') ?? 0;
  }
```

Set:

```
  Future<void> setHighScore() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (_score > _highscore) {
      _highscore = _score;
      await prefs.setInt('highScore', _highscore);
    }
  }
```

Currently I pass results of each quiz to a ScorePage like so:

```
if (quiz.length == questionNumber) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new ScorePage(quiz.score, quiz.length)), (Route route) => route == null);
              return;
            }
```

And I understand that. But I am having difficulty either displaying a storage value, or both storing and displaying a value.

quiz.dart (where I set high score)

```
import './question.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Quiz {
  List<Question> _questions;
  int _currentQuestionIndex = -1;
  int _score = 0;
  int _highScore; //new

  Quiz(this._questions) {
    _questions.shuffle();
  }

  List<Question> get questions => _questions;
  int get length => _questions.length;
  int get questionNumber => _currentQuestionIndex + 1;
  int get score => _score;

  Question get nextQuestion {
    _currentQuestionIndex++;
    if (_currentQuestionIndex >= length) return null;
    return _questions[_currentQuestionIndex];
  }

  void answer (bool isCorrect) {
    if (isCorrect) _score++;
  }

  Future<void> setHighScore() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (_score > _highScore) {
      _highScore = _score;
      await prefs.setInt('highScore', _highScore);
    }
  }
}
```

high_score_page.dart (where I get high score)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'landing_page.dart';

class HighScorePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HighScorePageState createState() => _HighScorePageState();
}

class _HighScorePageState extends State<HighScorePage> {
  int _highScore;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadHighScore();
  }

  _loadHighScore() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _highScore = (prefs.getInt('highScore') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Material(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            new Text("Your high score: ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 50.0),),
```

I have tried different things like:

```
new Text(_highScore.toString() // always returns 0
new Text(_loadHighScore() // returns type Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of 'String'
new Text('$_highScore' // always returns 0
```

I have only been able to output 0 or an error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you should declare a sharepreference each time you want to use it.

I created a template to create 'simple on-line app' at the following address:

https://github.com/lhcdims/fluttertemplate02

One of its features is how to use SharedPreferences.

Pls. pay attention to the 3 functions: Init(), getstring(), setstring() inside class gv of  GlobalVariable.dart, on how to define functions for all get/set strings.  You may write your own for get/set integers.

and also see the main() inside main.dart on how to use the functions.

BTW, sooner or later you'll find out setstate() is not a good solution for all types of App, you'll be finally using BloC or Redux, the template also demonstrates how to use Redux.